# What is the order of the largest subset of M_n(Z_p) such that no two elements commute?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra

Let $A(n,p)$ be the order of the largest subset of $M_n(Z_p)$ such that no two distinct matrices in this subset commute. Is it true that $\lim_{p \to \infty} \dfrac{A(n,p)}{p^{n^2}} =1$? Can anyone find better asymptotics?

Also, what happens if we fix $p$ and allow $n$ to grow?

(Inspired by 1990 Putnam B3)

Comment: Given that one can only select at most one regular semisimple element from each maximal torus, it seems to me that one can't exceed $O(p^{n^2-1})$ elements (and probably less than that if one works more carefully.)

Comment: I think that should be $O(p^{n^2-n})$, not $n^2-1$.

Comment: I don't think it can get lower than $O(p^{n^2−n})$. In fact, a lower bound is $A(n,p)\geq p^{\frac{n^2+n-2}{2}}(p^{n-2}-1)\cdots(p^2-1)(p-1)$

Comment: Is that by picking one diagonal matrix for each essentially different way to diagonalize?

Comment: @Gjergji, can you show me how you got that lower bound? Thanks!

Comment: Can you count them for, say, $n=2$ and arbitrary $p$, and then look up the results in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Abelian coverings of finite general linear groups and an application to their non-commuting graph](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3402v1.pdf) by A. Azad, M. A. Iranmanesh, C. E. Praeger, P. Spiga for the general linear group, one has that the ratio of the largest pairwise non-commuting set of invertible matrices in $GL(n,q)$ to the order of $GL(n,q)$ is something like $q^{-n}$.  One would guess that the answer should be the same since in some sense the unit group dominates the whole monoid.